# String to datetime conversion error in Powershell v5

Tags: powershell, datetime, powershell-5.0

I have a problem with 2 lines of code, which don't work as I expect. The point is that the `DateTime` object is being converted to `string` and back to DateTime, using default conversion, without explicit format specification.

```
$timeString = [DateTime]::Now.ToString() # contains 17.01.2017 20:01:30
$time = [DateTime]$timeString # PS blows with error
```

So, basically, it uses the default date format to format the string, but then it seem to use some other format to parse it back. The following line of code will work, however:

```
$otherTime = [DateTime]"01/17/2017 20:01:30" # will get the initial date
```

Could someone point me to proper documentation on the matter of types conversion, and why in this case it would use different formats to convert data back and forth?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was not able to replicate your issue. The first script block worked just fine.

Comment: Use `[string][DateTime]::Now` or `[DateTime]::Now.ToString([CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing dates is always a nightmare. Especially if you live in the tiny part of the world that is called 'outside US' :)

In general formatting and parsing dates in .NET (and many other things as string comparison) are controlled by culture settings. In some cases then default behavior is to use the current culture settings. `Convert.ToDateTime` is one of them. If you take a look into the documentation ([Convert.ToDateTime Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx)) it says:

> If value is not null, the return value is the result of invoking the
>   DateTime.Parse method on value using the formatting information in a
>   DateTimeFormatInfo object that is **initialized for the current culture**.
>   The value argument must contain the representation of a date and time
>   in one of the formats described in the DateTimeFormatInfo topic.

That's why it converts from your localized date string. In other cases the default behavior is to use the '*Invariant Culture*' setting which usually means '*US settings*'. Most of the methods are overloaded and can take a parameter that specifies the culture that should use, but it requires a little search into the .NET documentation.

As a rule of thumb: Don't use strings that are localized if they are not going to be shown to the end user. Always try to find the 'Invariant Culture' variant of the method, and use it for formatting and parsing of the strings. It will save you from many headaches.

Answer (score 2):

You're implicitly calling [`Convert.ToDateTime(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx), but this method's valid formats are hardcoded (and don't appear to be listed). From your output date format, I see that you're likely not in the US, which is probably what most of the formats are centered towards.

Instead, you can explicitly use [`Convert.ToDateTime(String, IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t(v=vs.110).aspx) to tell it which culture format provider you want.

```
[Convert]::ToDateTime($timeString, [System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo)
```

I'm on a US system, so I'm not entirely certain if this will work yet.

You can also use [`[DateTime]::TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`[DateTime]::TryParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) to explicitly specify the format(s) you want.

Comment: Yes, I use different culture, where format is `dd.MM.yyyy`, and the separator is `dot`. I did more investigation, and it happens that `[System.Convert]::ToDateTime("01/18/2017")` throws exception, while `[System.Convert]::ToDateTime("18.01.2017")` return valid date of Jan, 18th. So, it doesn't seem like it call `Convert.ToDateTime` method, at least with no params. Maybe it passes invariant culture to it, who knows.

Comment: Basically, my question was not about workarounds, but about the technical explanation for why it works the way it works. Maybe we need to file a bug somewhere :)